# Probability of $(X \leq 2Y)$

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent and their probability density functions are
$$f_X(t)=f_Y(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{l} e^{-t},\:\text{if $t \geq 0$;} \\ 0,\:\text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.$$

$P(X \leq 2Y)$=? (The probability of $X \leq 2Y$)

Comment: You can use the PDF's and integrate over a bounded area (i.e. the area between $0$ and $X = 2Y$) to get this, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the joint density is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-x}e^{-y}$.

To find the probability that $X\leq 2Y$ you need to evaluate
$$\text{P}(X\leq 2Y)=\text{P}\left(Y\geq \frac{X}{2}\right)=\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}\int_{y=\frac{x}{2}}^{y=\infty}e^{-x}e^{-y}dxdy\\=\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}\left[\int_{y=\frac{x}{2}}^{y=\infty}e^{-y}dy\right]e^{-x}dx\\=\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}\left[-e^{-y}\right]_{y=\frac{x}{2}}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx\\=\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}e^{-\frac{3x}{2}}dx=-\frac{2}{3}\left[e^{-\frac{3x}{2}}\right]_0^\infty=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Would it make any difference if it was $Y\leq 2X$

Comment: You would end up with the same result as $$P(Y\leq 2X)=P(X\geq\frac{Y}{2})=\int_{y=0}^{y=\infty}\left[\int_{x=\frac{y}{2}}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx\right]e^{-y}dy$$ The main thing to note is that the densities of $X$ and $Y$ are identical as well as being independent, which will lead to the same result. However, if $X$ and $Y$ had densities with different parameters, you would end up with a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $f_{X,Y}(s, t) = e^{-s}e^{-t} = e^{-(s+t)}$, $s, t > 0$.

Find the region where $X \leq 2Y$ and integrate appropriately.

Comment: My problem is this. I could not draw the graph.